# Increasing object allocations, While checking object allocations in the Instruments

Tags: objective-c

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = nil;
    annView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"]autorelease];
    for(int i=0;i<[List count];i++)
    {
        Small *Obj=[List objectAtIndex:i];
        if([[annView.annotation title] isEqualToString:Obj.streetAddress])
        {
            annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
            annView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
            annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [annView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];

        }

    }

    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use Instruments to look at object allocations, this is only valid if you have switched off Zombie setting in the Schema related to the target.  This is because Zombies will turn any released object into a Zombie instead of releasing it.